# React yup typecript Argument of type 'DefaultTFuncReturn' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Message<{}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup, react-scripts

I have this code snippet which worked correctly without any issue

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .required(translate('validations.organization.name', 'Organization name is required.'))
      .max(
        30,
        translate('validations.organization.max', 'Maximum length for the organization name is 30.')
      )
      .min(
        2,
        translate('validations.organization.min', 'Minimum length for the organization name is 2.')
      ),
  });
```

Then I upgrade my project's all packages to the latest npm package. Including `react`,`react-dom`, `react-scripts` linting, and `typescript`

**After that, I get this error in a lot of places**

Functions like `max`, `min` we can pass a string as a second argument. But error saying here is

> Argument of type 'DefaultTFuncReturn' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Message<{}> | undefined'.

That also makes sense, `DefaultTFuncReturn` is not equal to `Message<{}>`

I want to fix this error quickly since my goal is to check whether the package upgrade was successful or not. So how can I quickly fix this error globally without ts-ignore ignore every file?
[image]

Comment: Could you add a sandbox link as well ?